# Populate a structure

Tags: vb.net

I have a structure containing 47 fields.I also have a string that contains "|" delimited value . I want to populate the structure with the values in the string. The only solution that I can think of is below.However this involves hardcoding. Is there a better way to achieve the same via a loop or anything else

```
 Dim lobjStructData As New SUB_PNDGORDR_QRY_RESP
        Dim lstrarrStream As String() = pstrStream.Split(CChar("|"))

        lobjStructData.ClientId = CType(lstrarrStream(0), Char())
        lobjStructData.PortfolioId = CShort(lstrarrStream(1))
        lobjStructData.Currency = CType(lstrarrStream(2), Char())
        lobjStructData.ProductId = CType(lstrarrStream(3), Char())
        lobjStructData.InstrumentClass = CShort(lstrarrStream(4))
        lobjStructData.OrderSymbol = CType(lstrarrStream(5), Char())
        lobjStructData.Qty = CDbl(lstrarrStream(6))
        lobjStructData.QtyRemaining = CDbl(lstrarrStream(7))
        lobjStructData.OrderPrice = CDbl(lstrarrStream(8))
        lobjStructData.TriggerPrice = CDbl(lstrarrStream(9))
        lobjStructData.Remarks = CType(lstrarrStream(10), Char())
        lobjStructData.QtyDiscRem = CDbl(lstrarrStream(11))
        lobjStructData.OrderDateTime = CInt(lstrarrStream(12))
        lobjStructData.IntOrderNo = CDbl(lstrarrStream(13))
        lobjStructData.OrderStat = CType(lstrarrStream(14), Char())
        lobjStructData.DiscQty = CDbl(lstrarrStream(15))
        lobjStructData.SerialNo = CInt(lstrarrStream(16))
        lobjStructData.OpenCloseFlg = CInt(lstrarrStream(17))
        lobjStructData.InstrumentId = CInt(lstrarrStream(18))
        lobjStructData.ContractSeriesId = CInt(lstrarrStream(19))
        lobjStructData.InstrumentType = CShort(lstrarrStream(20))
        lobjStructData.BuySellInd = CShort(lstrarrStream(21))
        lobjStructData.MinFillQty = CDbl(lstrarrStream(22))
        lobjStructData.ExchId = CInt(lstrarrStream(23))
        lobjStructData.OrderTyp = CShort(lstrarrStream(24))
        lobjStructData.ValidityCond = CDbl(lstrarrStream(25))
        lobjStructData.ExchTrdNo = CType(lstrarrStream(26), Char())
        lobjStructData.IntTranscode = CShort(lstrarrStream(27))
        lobjStructData.ValidityAttr = CInt(lstrarrStream(28))
        lobjStructData.BosRefId = CInt(lstrarrStream(29))
        lobjStructData.OriginatorId = CType(lstrarrStream(30), Char())
        lobjStructData.Commision = CDbl(lstrarrStream(31))
        lobjStructData.SolicitedFlg = CType(lstrarrStream(32), Char())
        lobjStructData.OrderFamily = CType(lstrarrStream(33), Char())
        lobjStructData.ReceiptTime = CInt(lstrarrStream(34))
        lobjStructData.ExchShortSellFlag = CType(lstrarrStream(35), Char())
        lobjStructData.cSourceFlag = CChar(lstrarrStream(36))
        lobjStructData.extnno = CInt(lstrarrStream(37))
        lobjStructData.sReceiptMode = CType(lstrarrStream(38), Char())
        lobjStructData.sErrorMsg = CType(lstrarrStream(39), Char())
        lobjStructData.cCoverUncover = CChar(lstrarrStream(40))
        lobjStructData.fATOrderNo = CDbl(lstrarrStream(41))
        lobjStructData.iQtyCond = CShort(lstrarrStream(42))
        lobjStructData.iReserve2 = CChar(lstrarrStream(43))
        lobjStructData.fInternalRefId = CDbl(lstrarrStream(44))
```

Comment: No, there is no other approach since your logic is hardcoding the index of the string in the `String()` with a specific property.

Comment: Basically I have a text file with "|" delimited values.Each line in this text file is in sync with the structure mentioned above.
I need to populate this structure with the entry from the text file one at a time.Is there any other way by which i can avoid the hardcoding & redundancy?

Comment: Does the text-file have a header line? In general, no, there is no other way. I won't suggest a reflection approach (which could help to find the property if you store it's name in a `Dictionary(Of String, Int32)`, but that's a very error-prone and ugly way imo).

Comment: No the text file does not have a header line ,but if required it can be included

Comment: It doesn't help much since you have to map each property to the headername anyway. That could be achieved with reflection if the headers were same but once you change that in future your code will break silently. That's one reason why i avoid reflection. I have one project where i used Levenshtein distance  to calculate the String similarity of a header-column with a property. If there was one with a maximum distance of 50 i used it. But that is much code for this task and it is still error-prone.

Comment: But you could have  alook at [CSV Helper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) which has auto mapping features. I haven't tested it, it seems to initialize the properties in the order they appear with the column-order in the file or from a mapping-file. That might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a few redundancies here:

1. the data type you convert to (which is probably the same as the data type of the field),
2. the position in the array (which is the same as the order in which you write the statement),
3. the name of the result variable,
4. the name of the stream.

Let's try to get rid of them. We will remove (1) with method overloads, (2) with an auto-incremented position variable, (3) with a shorter variable name and (4) by extracting the conversion code into a method.

The following code is untested, but the idea should be obvious:

```
Public Function ParseStream(pstrStream As String) As SUB_PNDGORDR_QRY_RESP
    Dim p As New Parser(pstrStream)
    Dim r As New SUB_PNDGORDR_QRY_RESP()
    With r
        p.ParseField(.ClientId)
        p.ParseField(.PortfolioId)
        p.ParseField(.Currency)
        ...
    End With

    Return r
End Function 

Private Class Parser
    Public Sub New(pstrStream As String)
       Me.lstrarrStream = pstrStream.Split("|"c)
    End Sub

    Private pos As Integer = 0
    Private lstrarrStream As String()

    Public Sub ParseField(ByRef field As Char())
        field = CType(lstrarrStream(pos), Char())
        pos += 1
    End Sub

    Public Sub ParseField(ByRef field As Short)
        field = CShort(lstrarrStream(pos))
        pos += 1
    End Sub

    ... other ParseField overloads...
End Class
```