# Setting a VB.NET object property when I don't know which property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a VB class. It's big, so I'm posting a simplified example here:

```
Public Class ExampleClass
    Public Property Foo As String
    Public Property Bar As String
End Class
```

Suppose I have a text file like this:

```
foo,123
bar,456
```

And I want to read the file and populate the properties of my object accordingly.

Simplest way I can think of is to add a method with a case statement, like this:

```
Public Class ExampleClass
    Public Property Foo As String
    Public Property Bar As String
    Public Sub SetProperty(prop As String, val As String)
        Select Case prop
            Case "Foo"
                Foo = val
            Case "Bar"
                Bar = val
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

But as my class will have around a hundred properties, so my SetProperty procedure is going to get big and boring to put together, and probably not be the most maintainable. Is there a better way to do this?

Before you tell me, I shouldn't structure my data this way, I know. However, this is a legacy database table that I have to live with. I'm updating the application with some new Entity Framework and LINQ code that will allow me to drop some very ugly stored procedures.

Thanks for your help.

James

Comment: Are you a co-worker of this question's OP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822402/populate-a-structure#comment47775946_29822402 As mentioned there in the comments you could have a look  at [CSV Helper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) which has auto mapping features. It either initializes the properties in the order they appear   in the file or from a mapping-file. That might work for you.

Comment: You can use reflection to set property value.

Comment: Use reflection, example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970353/c-sharp-dynamically-set-property

Answer (score 1):

You can find each object property via reflection

```
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = myClass.GetType().GetProperty("Foo");

        if (pi  != null && pi.CanWrite)
        {
           //Check the type before assignment...
           if (pi.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)))
               pi.SetValue(myClass, value, null);
        }
```